# How to create a dynamic price range filter using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

**price range aggregations**

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "price_ranges": {
      "range": {
        "field": "price",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": 50
          },
          {
            "from": 50,
            "to": 100
          },
          {
            "from": 100
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "price_stats": {
      "extended_stats": {
        "field": "price"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can make the ranges dynamic. for example, min_price in place of 50 and max_price in place of 100. Or use something like "price_stats.max" for max_price?

Comment: What do you mean dynamic? You want to be able to pass something like a variable or min_price should actually be the minimum value from field `price`?

Comment: Yes like variables. An example app would be a store that's selling wedding ring with prices ranging from $500 to $4,000 might also be selling flash disk with prices ranging from $5 to $10. Static value wound irrelevant aggs. It it can be achieved using script an example would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible today and it's been brought up before: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9572. As the github issue says, the only option is to execute two queries.

Comment: Useful information. Thank you Andrei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get something like this

```
"max_price" : { "max" : { "field" : "discountprice" } },
"min_price" : { "min" : { "field" : "discountprice" } }
```

then create a range in application layer